# Pydev codecoverage results don't appear

Tags: python, eclipse, code-coverage, pydev

I have set up the codecoverage to run with pydev, but the results don't appear.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297294/integrating-command-line-generated-python-coverage-files-with-pydev) I found the .coverage file at ~/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/coverage, and that works properly (gives the result when running coverage report there, gets empty when I do it from pydev, etc).

Does somebody know where can I configure the path to get the results to the Eclipse plugin?

Comment: Hard to know what was wrong without more info... can you give the steps you're following which are not working? Are you following http://pydev.org/manual_adv_coverage.html?

Comment: I have installed the coveragy.py program with pydev following: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_coverage.html All steps work, except the reports at the report window, that don't appear.  But I know that the info is actually generated at the indicated directory. 
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 and pydev 3.5.0

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem and the solution was to install *coverage* from 3.x branch (i.e. `pip install "coverage < 4.0.0"`).

There's a hint on [PyDev coverage documentation page](http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_coverage.html):

> ... the integration is tested with version 3.4, so, this is the recommended version.

Coverage v4 has default report file name and its format changed. Older file name was `~/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/coverage/.coverage` and it contained binary [`marshal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html)'ed output (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/297764/2072035)). Newer is in `~/.metadata/.plugins/org.python.pydev.debug/coverage/.coverage.0` and it contains JSON string prefixed with *!coverage.py: This is a private format, don't read it directly!* ;-)